# Defining a variable in a function python

Tags: python

I have a function which has an if statement and asks for user input.

```py
def my_function():
    answer = input(";")
    if condition 1
        a = 1
    else
        a = 0
```

I then want to run the function like so
'''
my_funnction()
'''
Then I want to extract the value of a based on the outcome of the function.
When I try to do this it says the variable is undefined. When I define the variable, a, outside the function then its value doesn't change. How can I have the value of my variable be extracted from the function?

Comment: Return it from the function. A variable is local, by definition. Or put your function inside a class and declare the variable as an instance attribute of the class.

Comment: You define the variable `a` and give it a value, but like all variables defined inside functions you throw it away (along with its value) once the function terminates. You can return values from functions using `return`, but the names of variables remain inaccessible.

Comment: Do you want to return the input value or only return `a` based on input was true or false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the easiest way.

```
def my_function():
    answer = input(";")

    if condition 1
        my_function.a = 1 #just add the function name to the variable
    else
        my_function.a = 0 #here also
```

Then

```
print(my_function.a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Nobody has access to function's local namespace. `a` is only accessible during the execution of the `my_function`.

You should return the value from the function and then do whatever you want with it later:

```py
def my_function():
    answer = input(";")
    if condition 1
        a = 1
    else:
        a = 0
    return a

a = my_function()
```

Another solution which I don't recommend is using `global` keyword:

```py
def my_function():
    global a
    if True:
        a = 1
    else:
        a = 0

my_function()
print(a)
```

By saying so, you make changes in global namespace. That's why you can access it later. (You don't have to define it in global namespace first)

However with a simple search you can find hundreds of articles [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19158418/13944524) about why using global variables is not recommended and why functions should be isolated.